# Looking for modules/classes specified by string

Tags: python, python-module

I want to find all classes in a module that inherits a "base class", and the module is specified by a string.
E.g.

```
for c in find_classes('robo.extras.contrib') :
 o = c()
 o.process(argv = self.argv[1:])
```

In the above example, `find_classes` looks through all modules in `robo.extras.contrib` for classes that inherits a class with the method `process`, instantiates it and runs the method.

I have been looking through python.org but doesn't seem to find the answer on this one, if anyone could point me in the right direction or even give me a quick sample here I'd be very happy.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import inspect, importlib
def find_classes(module, with_method=None):
    module = importlib.import_module(module)
    return [
        c for _, c in inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass)
        if not with_method or with_method in dir(c)
    ]
```

and then:

```
for c in find_classes('robo.extras.contrib', with_method='process'):
...
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! I expected it to be much more complicated, but your snippet is short and easy to understand. Thanks :)